# Openshift - Is posible install cron job cartridge in all gears?

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

Openshift - Is posible install cron job cartridge in all gears?
The problem that I have is write a shell script file in cron job directory, but in a scalable app only one gear contains cron job. It is a way to have cron jobs in all gears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron cartridge gets installed on all web gears and executes on all of those gears.  It not, however, installed on any other cartridge gears, unless they are custom cartridges and specify to install cron alongside them.  You can use the rhc app show  --gears to view which cartridges are on which gears.